# shopoify liquid tags if else unless

Tags: shopify, liquid

I need to customize the shipping confirmation email. I want to use a tag to determine which of two text sections are included in the email. The problem is there is usually an array of tags. I can get section "A" like this...

{% for tag in tags %}
{% if tag == 'a' %}
A
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}

There is only a single 'a' tag in the array so I only get the "A" text once.

But I can't figure out how to get the "B" text to appear just one time.

If I do this, it appears for every tag that does not == 'a'...

{% for tag in tags %}
{% unless tag contains 'a' %}
B
{% endunless %}
{% endfor %}

Is there a way to get one instance of "B"?

Comment: Why can't you just repeat the same logic for B? `{% for tag in tags %} {% if tag == 'a' %} A {% endif%} {% if tag == 'b' %} B {% endif %} {% endfor %}`

Comment: The problem is that there is no specific value for "B" The "B" condition is the absence of the "A" value in any of the tags. Say i use "else" for no "A" condition and there are three tags total.If one tag equals "A" but the others do not, I get the "A" section, but I also get the "B" section twice.

Comment: I've added an answer, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could repeat the same logic you did for A:

```html
{% for tag in tags %}
  {% if tag == 'a' %}
    A
  {% endif %}
  {% if tag == 'b' %}
    B
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Alternatively you could do a switch/case statement, I'd prefer this approach because it's easy to read, and if sometime in the future you would like to add another condition (tag), it would be easy and the code would still keep its elegance.

```html
{% for tag in tags %}
  {% case tag %}
    {% when 'a' %}
      A
    {% when 'b' %}
      B
    {% when 'c' %}
      C
  {% endcase %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have many tags it can become tricky, but if it's just two tags this is the general idea.

```
{% assign a_not_found = true %}
{% for tag in tags %}
  {% if tag == 'a' %}
    ...
    {% assign a_not_found = false %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% if a_not_found %}
  {... show b... }
{% endif %}
```

Otherwise

```
{% if tags contains 'a' %}
{...show a...%}
{% else %}
{...show b...%}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I tried your code but got both A and B. I think the  issue might be there is both "a_not_found" and "a_found". Should the last "if" be "if a_found == false" since that would mean "a" was found?

Comment: I was also trying to make an array of all the tags and see if the array contains "a". Do you know how to code that? Seems top use "capture" and "split" operations but I can't figure it out.

Comment: @webguy Sorry there was an error in the code. I also added a contains example.